# Filters doesn't work as expected in win forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataview

I am trying to apply row filter to existing datagridview table. The table has a column 'Name' and a checkbox.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Name like '%{0}%'",  textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable();  
}
```

The issue is when I type a letter it filters accordingly but then it creates a new column in table and populates filtered values there instead of applying filter in same column.

Comment: Creating a new `DataView` every time the textbox is updated is expensive, there are cheaper ways of doing this, such as simply updating an existing DataView's filter and refreshing the grid.

Comment: No, this doesn't happen here. There must be something else going on in your code.. What are the names of the added columns you are seeing? -  And yes this would be better: `DataView dv = null;
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    if (dv == null)dv = new DataView(DT);..}`

Comment: TAW, the name of column added  is Names.

Comment: Also, the modification you suggested didn't work. Now the columns checkbox and 'Name' are created in the design view.

Comment: `dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns` = `false`